# Store simple value in a matrix in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, matrix

I have a simple program that `scanf` a value at a time then store it in a row (p) then store it in a matrix (pg).

```c
//
// Created by herveDarritchon on 15/01/2022.
//

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int dim = 0;
    printf("dim ?\n");
    scanf("%d", &dim);
    short tab[dim];
    short *p;
    short **pg;
    p = &tab[0];
    short tab_double[dim][dim];
    pg = (short **) &tab_double[0];

    for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            printf("value: ");
            scanf("%d", &p[i]);
            printf("value stored : %d\n", p[i]);
        }

        printf("value in tab: ");

        for (int l = 0; l < dim; l++) {
            printf("%d|", tab[l]);
        }

        printf("\n");
        pg[j] = tab;
        printf("value ub pg[%d]: ", j);

        for (int l = 0; l < dim; l++) {
            printf("%d|", pg[j][l]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
        printf("value ub pg[%d]: ", k);

        for (int l = 0; l < dim; l++) {
            printf("%d|", pg[k][l]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Result is

```
dim ?
2
value: 1
value stored : 1
value: 2        
value stored : 2    
value in tab: 1|2|  
value ub pg[0]: 1|2|
value: 3
value stored : 3
value: 4
value stored : 4
value in tab: 3|4|
value ub pg[1]: 3|4|
value ub pg[0]: 3|4|
value ub pg[1]: 3|4|
```

But at the end, the matrix (pg) only stores the last row in all its index :(

I think I did something wrong with pointers ... but I can't figure out why the matrix has only the last row.

Comment: `pg[j] = tab;` is not doing what you think. Only the adress of `tab` is copied.

Comment: Is there a reason to not storing the values directly in the "matrix"? Why are you introducing all those pointers?

Comment: An array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array. Also an array of arrays is not the same as a pointer to pointer.

Comment: @Bob__ In fact at the end I'd like to use only pointers and no array at all. It is some sort of intermediate solution. But I can't make it work like that.

Comment: @Damien Do you think I should do something like `pg[j][i]=tab[i];` instead of `pg[j] = tab;`?

Comment: Why not modifying `tab_double` directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
pg = &tab_double[0];
```

was giving you a compiler warning. You seem to have suppressed this warning by adding a type cast:

```
pg = (short **) &tab_double[0];
```

However, it was not a good idea to suppress the compiler warning like that. The compiler was pointing out that something was wrong.

With the line

```
short tab_double[dim][dim];
```

you are declaring a two-dimensional (2D) array.

A 2D array is nothing more than an array of arrays. The inner arrays are of type `short[dim]` (array of `dim` elements, where each element is of type `short`) and the outer array is of type `short[dim][dim]` (array of `dim` elements, where each element is of type `short[dim]`).

If you want `pg` to point to the first element of the outer array, then you should make its type reflect this. You want it to point to an element of type `short[dim]`. Therefore, the type of the pointer should be `short (*)[dim]` (the parentheses are necessary, because otherwise the type would be an array of pointers to objects of type `short`). So you should declare the pointer like this:

```
short (*pg)[dim];
```

However, you are instead declaring the pointer like this:

```
short **pg;
```

This tells the compiler that `pg` will be pointing to a pointer to a `short`. However, this information is incorrect. As mentioned above, you want it to point to an object of type `short[dim]` (i.e. to an array of `dim` elements of type `short`).

An array is not a pointer (although arrays often [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to pointers in certain situations).

After fixing this, your compiler will now give you an error in the following line:

```
pg[j] = tab;
```

This is because you cannot directly assign a value to an array. However, you can

- copy one element at a time from one array to another array in a loop, until the entire array is copied, or
- copy the memory contents of one array to another array, using [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing arrays with pointers and seem to assume they are somehow the same. That is not true.

Look at the memory layout:

```c
short arr[dim][dim];
```

In memory this looks like this (assume `dim==3`):

```
 +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
 |    +0   |    +2   |    +4   |    +6   |    +8   |    +A   |    +C   |    +E   |   +10   |
 +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
 |arr[0][0]|arr[0][1]|arr[0][2]|arr[1][0]|arr[1][1]|arr[1][2]|arr[2][0]|arr[2][1]|arr[2][2]|
 +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

This is similar to your `short tab_double[dim][dim];`

On the other side look at this:

```c
short **pg;
```

In memory this looks like this (assume 32 bit addresses):

```c
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |    +0    |    +4    |    +8    |
 +----------+----------+----------+
 |   pg[0]  |   pg[1]  |   pg[2]  |
 +----------+----------+----------+
```

and furthermore it depends on the content of `p[x]` where `p[x][0]` is located.

As you can see, the memory layout of `short **pg` is very different from `short tab_double[dim][dim]`

With that assignment `pg = (short **) &tab_double[0];` you tell your compiler to treat the memory that holds the first few elements of your array as an array of pointers. That causes memory corruption.